# Fast input class-Can't understand this class

Tags: performance, c++11, time

I have seen some people using this FastInput class to improve their compile time,but I am not able to understand the functions inside it clearly.My question is:What do I need to study to understand these functions, and how this class improves the overall time.It will be helpful if someone can explain the functions inside this class and what do they do or atleast please give some good references .

```
class FastInput {
    public:
        FastInput() {
            m_dataOffset = 0;
            m_dataSize = 0;
            m_v = 0x80000000;
        }
        uint32_t ReadNext() {
            if (m_dataOffset == m_dataSize) {
                int r = read(0, m_buffer, sizeof(m_buffer));
                if (r <= 0) return m_v;
                m_dataOffset = 0;
                m_dataSize = 0;
                int i = 0;
                if (m_buffer[0] < '0') {
                    if (m_v != 0x80000000) {
                        m_data[m_dataSize++] = m_v;
                        m_v = 0x80000000;
                    }
                    for (; (i < r) && (m_buffer[i] < '0'); ++i);
                }
                for (; i < r;) {
                    if (m_buffer[i] >= '0') {
                        m_v = m_v * 10 + m_buffer[i] - 48;
                        ++i;
                    } else {
                        m_data[m_dataSize++] = m_v;
                        m_v = 0x80000000;
                        for (i = i + 1; (i < r) && (m_buffer[i] < '0'); ++i);
                    }
                }
            }
            return m_data[m_dataOffset++];
        }
    public:
        uint8_t m_buffer[32768];
        uint32_t m_data[16384];
        size_t m_dataOffset, m_dataSize;
        uint32_t m_v;
};
class FastOutput {
    public:
        FastOutput() {
            m_dataOffset = 0;
        }
        ~FastOutput() {
        }
        void Flush() {
            if (m_dataOffset) {
                if (write(1, m_data, m_dataOffset));
                m_dataOffset = 0;
            }
        }
        void PrintUint(uint32_t v, char d) {
            if (m_dataOffset + 11 > sizeof(m_data)) Flush();
            if (v < 100000) {
                if (v < 1000) {
                    if (v < 10) {
                        m_data[m_dataOffset + 0] = v + 48;
                        m_dataOffset += 1;
                    } else if (v < 100) {
                        m_data[m_dataOffset + 1] = v - v / 10 * 10 + 48; v /= 10;
                        m_data[m_dataOffset + 0] = v + 48;
                        m_dataOffset += 2;
                    } else {
                        m_data[m_dataOffset + 2] = v - v / 10 * 10 + 48; v /= 10;
                        m_data[m_dataOffset + 1] = v - v / 10 * 10 + 48; v /= 10;
                        m_data[m_dataOffset + 0] = v + 48;
                        m_dataOffset += 3;
                    }
                } else {
                    if (v < 10000) {
                        m_data[m_dataOffset + 3] = v - v / 10 * 10 + 48; v /= 10;
                        m_data[m_dataOffset + 2] = v - v / 10 * 10 + 48; v /= 10;
                        m_data[m_dataOffset + 1] = v - v / 10 * 10 + 48; v /= 10;
                        m_data[m_dataOffset + 0] = v + 48;
                        m_dataOffset += 4;
                    } else {
                        m_data[m_dataOffset + 4] = v - v / 10 * 10 + 48; v /= 10;
                        m_data[m_dataOffset + 3] = v - v / 10 * 10 + 48; v /= 10;
                        m_data[m_dataOffset + 2] = v - v / 10 * 10 + 48; v /= 10;
                        m_data[m_dataOffset + 1] = v - v / 10 * 10 + 48; v /= 10;
                        m_data[m_dataOffset + 0] = v + 48;
                        m_dataOffset += 5;
                    }
                }
            } else {
                if (v < 100000000) {
                    if (v < 1000000) {
                        m_data[m_dataOffset + 5] = v - v / 10 * 10 + 48; v /= 10;
                        m_data[m_dataOffset + 4] = v - v / 10 * 10 + 48; v /= 10;
                        m_data[m_dataOffset + 3] = v - v / 10 * 10 + 48; v /= 10;
                        m_data[m_dataOffset + 2] = v - v / 10 * 10 + 48; v /= 10;
                        m_data[m_dataOffset + 1] = v - v / 10 * 10 + 48; v /= 10;
                        m_data[m_dataOffset + 0] = v + 48;
                        m_dataOffset += 6;
                    } else if (v < 10000000) {
                        m_data[m_dataOffset + 6] = v - v / 10 * 10 + 48; v /= 10;
                        m_data[m_dataOffset + 5] = v - v / 10 * 10 + 48; v /= 10;
                        m_data[m_dataOffset + 4] = v - v / 10 * 10 + 48; v /= 10;
                        m_data[m_dataOffset + 3] = v - v / 10 * 10 + 48; v /= 10;
                        m_data[m_dataOffset + 2] = v - v / 10 * 10 + 48; v /= 10;
                        m_data[m_dataOffset + 1] = v - v / 10 * 10 + 48; v /= 10;
                        m_data[m_dataOffset + 0] = v + 48;
                        m_dataOffset += 7;
                    } else {
                        m_data[m_dataOffset + 7] = v - v / 10 * 10 + 48; v /= 10;
                        m_data[m_dataOffset + 6] = v - v / 10 * 10 + 48; v /= 10;
                        m_data[m_dataOffset + 5] = v - v / 10 * 10 + 48; v /= 10;
                        m_data[m_dataOffset + 4] = v - v / 10 * 10 + 48; v /= 10;
                        m_data[m_dataOffset + 3] = v - v / 10 * 10 + 48; v /= 10;
                        m_data[m_dataOffset + 2] = v - v / 10 * 10 + 48; v /= 10;
                        m_data[m_dataOffset + 1] = v - v / 10 * 10 + 48; v /= 10;
                        m_data[m_dataOffset + 0] = v + 48;
                        m_dataOffset += 8;
                    }
                } else {
                    if (v < 1000000000) {
                        m_data[m_dataOffset + 8] = v - v / 10 * 10 + 48; v /= 10;
                        m_data[m_dataOffset + 7] = v - v / 10 * 10 + 48; v /= 10;
                        m_data[m_dataOffset + 6] = v - v / 10 * 10 + 48; v /= 10;
                        m_data[m_dataOffset + 5] = v - v / 10 * 10 + 48; v /= 10;
                        m_data[m_dataOffset + 4] = v - v / 10 * 10 + 48; v /= 10;
                        m_data[m_dataOffset + 3] = v - v / 10 * 10 + 48; v /= 10;
                        m_data[m_dataOffset + 2] = v - v / 10 * 10 + 48; v /= 10;
                        m_data[m_dataOffset + 1] = v - v / 10 * 10 + 48; v /= 10;
                        m_data[m_dataOffset + 0] = v + 48;
                        m_dataOffset += 9;
                    } else {
                        m_data[m_dataOffset + 9] = v - v / 10 * 10 + 48; v /= 10;
                        m_data[m_dataOffset + 8] = v - v / 10 * 10 + 48; v /= 10;
                        m_data[m_dataOffset + 7] = v - v / 10 * 10 + 48; v /= 10;
                        m_data[m_dataOffset + 6] = v - v / 10 * 10 + 48; v /= 10;
                        m_data[m_dataOffset + 5] = v - v / 10 * 10 + 48; v /= 10;
                        m_data[m_dataOffset + 4] = v - v / 10 * 10 + 48; v /= 10;
                        m_data[m_dataOffset + 3] = v - v / 10 * 10 + 48; v /= 10;
                        m_data[m_dataOffset + 2] = v - v / 10 * 10 + 48; v /= 10;
                        m_data[m_dataOffset + 1] = v - v / 10 * 10 + 48; v /= 10;
                        m_data[m_dataOffset + 0] = v + 48;
                        m_dataOffset += 10;
                    }
                }
            }
            m_data[m_dataOffset++] = d;
        }
        void PrintChar(char d) {
            if (m_dataOffset + 1 > sizeof(m_data)) Flush();
            m_data[m_dataOffset++] = d;
        }
        void ReplaceChar(int offset, char d) {
            m_data[m_dataOffset + offset] = d;
        }
    public:
        uint8_t m_data[32768];
        size_t m_dataOffset;
};
FastInput g_fi;
FastOutput g_fo;
```

Comment: I saw what is written there,however no references are given in question to understand the code,and even if using this practice is bad,i still want to understand whY is "v - v / 10 * 10 + 48; v /= 10; " this done

Comment: `v-v/10*10` is precisely `v%10` (assuming `v` is non-negative, which it is where that is invoked). `48` is `'0'`; '0' would have been somewhat less cryptic and avoiding its use is simply bad style since it has no impact at all on compilation or execution time. So the expression could have been written as `'0'+v%10`. `v=/10` then divides `v` by 10, in order to move on to the next digit (to the left). Why was it done? My guess is "showing off"; it might save one or two cycles, but hardly worth it.